# How do I validate an unavailable period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm practicing rails and I would like to know how I would validate a situation.

In this case, it's a car rental project. I have a table of Cars (Autos) and one of Unavailable Period.

When registering a car, I assume that the car is available 100% of the month. If someone rents in a certain period, it must be unavailable so it can't be rented again in the same period, how would I do this validation?

Model

```
class UnavailablePeriod < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :auto
end
```

```
class Auto < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :rental_company
   belongs_to :category
   has_many :unavailable_periods
end
```

Any suggestion? content tip to study this?
What would be the best way?

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBegd.png)

Comment: it seems to me that you will need a table for Rent and this new model will need a custom validation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods.

Comment: thanks. worked, but I will do that study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an `UnavailablePeriod` I would simply have a `Rental` model that has a `rented_from` and a `rented_until` columns (both datetime).

On creation of a new Rental you then only have to check that there is no existing, date overlapping rental. to check that you could use a custom validation like this:

```
class Rental < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :auto

  validate :rental_period_is_available

  private

  def rental_period_is_available
    return unless Rental
        .where.not(id: id)
        .where("rented_from < ? && ? < rented_until", rented_until, rented_from) 
        .exist?

    errors.add(:base, "Car is already booked in this time period")
  end
end
```

I suggest reading about [custom validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) and [validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) in general in the [offical Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/).

Comment: thanks. worked, but I will do that study.